# Facebook Invite Friends not working on swit 4.0?

Tags: swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

Ive followed all the ways the internet tells me to invite friends using the facebook simulator but to alas it doesn't work.

```
let content = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
content.appLinkURL = URL(string: "testString")!
FBSDKAppInviteDialog.show(from: self.parent, with: content, delegate: self)
```

And its never working for me. The invite friends dialog does not appear. I am also using the simulator in XCOde. So my two questions are is there a different way I should be displaying the invite friends dialog? Also is there a specific set of instructions I need to follow to get the invite dialog to work on the simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible to invite friends using facebook anymore.

https://blog.markgrowth.com/deprecation-of-facebook-invitable-friends-graph-api-and-its-impact-on-organic-growth-f35677734b65

Comment: Yes they removed the feature to invite friends. But what really sucks is that facebook even removed the webpages in the developer docs that said they removed the friend invite feature. Thats retarded. They should have just left it in there. I don't understand why they would remove it.

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook App invites was deprecated back in Feb](https://blog.getsocial.im/facebook-deprecates-app-invites-are-you-ready/#acquisition). If you have a gaming app you can still use the GameRequest dialog. However, our data has shown that organic installs through Facebook are only 1% when compared to other channels like WhatsApp (see a [study by Sega and GetSocial](http://www.pocketgamer.biz/infographic/67748/sega-and-getsocial-study-on-viral-ua/)).

Disclaimer: I am the founder of [GetSocial](https://www.getsocial.im)